# OpenVPN: Doesn't close dead sockets, user limit reached

Tags: openvpn

I am running OpenVPN 2.3.1 with a fairly basic configuration. The daemon has been up in it's current configuration for ~180 days. Earlier this week I began to get connection failures to find out the connection limit has been reached. Status on the management terminal shows two different users with > 50 connections each. A TCP dump shows that those connections are not active, but are still established. No error messages reveal any possible problems.

Why isn't OpenVPN closing the dead sockets?

Relevant config options may be:

`duplicate-cn`

`crl-verify keys/crl.pem`

`keepalive 10 120`

Comment: Did you see anything in your syslog?   BTW, why are you permitting `duplicate-cn` that is generally frowned upon.

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary in the logs. I'm using the duplicate names so I don't have to keep track of separate keys for individual devices. If I want to revoke someone or they expose their key it's more simple to fix.

Comment: Have a look at the keepalive config option.